# CentOS Adding a user restricted to one directory

Tags: centos, permissions

What's the easiest and standard way to create and restrict a new user to /var/www/ in CentOS ?

Edit: Ideally restricted to SCP only.

Comment: Will this user have shell access, or do they simply need to be able to put files in /var/www?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a recent enough CentOS comes a new enough OpenSSH with `chroot` and `internal-sftp` features.

First you need to configure OpenSSH to use the internal SFTP. This is done by adding this line to `sshd.conf`:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Then you can add rules for restricting users / groups to their home directories:

```
  Match user restrictedjoe
  ChrootDirectory /var/www
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Or for groups

```
  Match group restrictedgroup
  ChrootDirectory /var/www
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite why is installing mysecureshell

http://mysecureshell.sourceforge.net/

It's the most config friendly option. You can do a lot of great things with it

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a "stadard way" but one method to do this is to create a so called "jail" for the user where his/her jail is /var/www. This can be done by creating a chroot jail. See the chroot command. The jail can also control what the user can do in the jail ie which commands/programs can be run.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply to my comment, I wouldn't give the user a full shell.  This makes the task far easier.  There are a few shell replacements that come to mind which can be used to allow the user to manage files and nothing else:

- [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/)
- [scponlyc](https://github.com/scponly/scponly)

I've personally used scponlyc a few times.  It even includes scripts to set up chroot jails for you ([github wiki](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki/Install#wiki-Additional_chroot_Specific_Steps))